# How to set global repositories for gradle that I can use them in each gradle project

Tags: maven, gradle, global, repository

It's slow to visit the maven official repositories from my country, so I want to try some local repositories first.

Is it able to add them to some global gradle configuration file, that I can just use them in each gradle project, without modifying the project-scope `build.gradle` file?

Answer (score 34):

I would suggest to use the [init.gradle](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/init_scripts.html) script which is located in your home folder `$HOME/.gradle/init.gradle` which might contain the following content:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
          url "http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note I also had to add the repositories  to a buildscript block like in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17773817/purpose-of-buildscript-block-in-gradle

Comment: "As a general advice, you should avoid adding mavenLocal() as a repository. " https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#sec:case-for-maven-local  Please edit your answer.

Comment: That would work for dependencies only. For plugins different semantics is required: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/9016#issuecomment-483581381

Answer (score 5):

I guess that what are You looking for are [init scripts](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/init_scripts.html).