# Error when migrating Crashlytics to Firebase Android

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, crashlytics

I'm basically following the migration guide from within Crashlytics (which is pretty much summarized in this [post](https://proandroiddev.com/migrating-crashlytics-to-the-firebase-console-5e05b6ff8c12)).

I followed the same instructions verbatim, you can see that from my `git diff`:

[image]

[image]

Yet when I sync my Gradle, I get this error:

> 5:02 PM   Gradle sync failed: Could not find method compile() for
>   arguments [com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.2] on object of type
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

## Update

As mentioned in the comments (and as experienced by us at the end), we shouldn't migrate anyway until further notice:

[image]

## Update 2

In fabric, if you click on Crashlytics, there is a link on the left nav bar that says Firebase, when you click on it you get this ad

[image]

Comment: Quick note - if you're currently using Fabric Crashlytics in your app we're recommending that you continue using it instead of migrating to Firebase Crashlytics right now. In the coming months, we'll have a migration path to easily move your apps to Firebase Crashlytics.

Comment: @Alexizamerican yeah figured.. see update to question. Please remove that invitation to migrate over to fabric from crashlytics in that case.. it's simply misleading

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Can you let me know where you're seeing the invitation? I can work with the team to make it less confusing.

Comment: @Alexizamerican updated answer again

Comment: Thanks - I can see why that's confusing and I'll definitely share with the team. Appreciate the feedback!

Comment: @abbood: please do not beg for votes here.

Comment: (The reason is that we want votes to be authentic and organic, rather than skewed by social contract or obligation).

Answer (score 1):

The `buildscript` block is not a place for your application level dependencies. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17773817/purpose-of-buildscript-in-gradle) for more information on the `buildscript` block.

You need to place your `compile` or `implementation`/`api`(for gradle 3.4+ and android gradle plugin 3.0+) dependencies into the separate `dependencies{}` block with the rest of your dependencies, that is usually on the same level as your `android` plugin configuration.

Answer (score 0):

- In your project level grade file, you need to add, `maven {
          url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
      }` to the repositories.
- add the following to your dependencies  `classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.1''`
- In your app level Gradle file put  `apply plugin: 'io.fabric'` below  `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` and under depencies place this  `implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.7.1@aar') {
      transitive = true
  }`
- place   `apply plugin:'com.google.gms.google-services'` at the bottom of the app level gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

Change `compile '...'` to `implementation '...'`

Answer (score 0):

You are using Google Services plugin 3.0.0.  The [instructions for adding the Crashlytics SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started#add_the_crashlytics_sdk_to_your_project) indicate that 3.1.2 or higher is required:

> Note: Crashlytics requires Google Services plugin version 3.1.2 or
>   higher. Check the com.google.gms:google-services version number in
>   your project's build.gradle dependencies.