# How can I get mybatis-spring using gradle?

Tags: gradle, mybatis

How can I download mybatis-spring by using gradle? Because I got message below message when I use "**`gradle eclipse`**". `"Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'. > Could not find org.mybatis:mybatis-spring:1.2.2."`

This is my `build.gradle` file.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.mybatis:mybatis-spring:1.2.2")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'


jar {
    baseName = 'mylib'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile("org.mybatis:mybatis-spring:1.2.2")
    testCompile("junit:junit:4.11")
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '1.8'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I bet that you will fix it using `mavenCentral()` instead of `mavenLocal()` inside your `buildscript` section. You probably don't have the dependency in your local maven repo.

Just as a reminder (it is a bit strange you need `mybatis-spring` dependency for the script itself), `buildscript` dependencies are for the script itself (See [59.5. External dependencies for the build script section in gradle's manual](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/organizing_build_logic.html), or [Gradle buildscript dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13923766/gradle-buildscript-dependencies)).