# Setup kotlin project with gradle

Tags: gradle, kotlin

I'm new to kotlin and gradle and tried to set up my very first project:

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
   ext.kotlin_version = '1.0.1-1'

   repositories {
     mavenCentral()
     jcenter()
   }

   dependencies {
     classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
   }
}

apply plugin: "kotlin"
```

src\main\kotlin\main.kt

```
package hello

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
   println("Hello World!")
}
```

And I get the error message "src\main\kotlin\main.kt: (4, 4): Unresolved reference: println".

The build.gradle file I copied from http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html

I'd expect that the standard libraries are included automatically - or do I need to add something here?

I'm using gradle 2.12, JDK 1.8. (in case this matters)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reference is missing the `kotlin-stdlib` dependency. It is not added automatically.

`kotlin-gradle-plugin` buildscript dependency is only Gradle plugin for Kotlin builds, and it doesn't add any dependencies to your project code. In order to use the standard library, one should add it as a dependency.

Append the following to your `build.gradle`:

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
}
```

(`jcenter()` is needed again, these `repositories` [are different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13923766/gradle-buildscript-dependencies) from those in `buildscript`)

Comment: jcenter() is better (uses https)

Comment: @hotkey Thanks for your very quick help!

Comment: As the kotlin version is defined as a property, I can use it in the dependency as well, I guess that's better to allow future changes: dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
}