# Kotlin setup for Gradle without IDE assistance - Kotlin classes not making it to classpath

Tags: java, gradle, kotlin

I am trying to create a Java sub-module using Gradle by myself. I followed the steps in http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html#using-Gradle albeit the split of some things in different Gradle files, and the IDE seems to recognize everything correctly, Kotlin source does not make it to the classpath. In https://github.com/stoyicker/master-slave-clean-store/tree/792c8207776846b0320c1e055521a288c9e63b5a you can see a snapshot of what fails.

Comment: Did you also add `kotlin-stdlib` as a dependency? See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36226278/setup-kotlin-project-with-gradle

Comment: Yes I did, the module's build.gradle adds the dependencies specified in buildsystem/dependencies.gradle.

Comment: What is the output of `gradlew dependencies`?, because I am not sure an array of strings is an acceptable way to specify dependencies.

Comment: It is just as it should be, the std-lib bringing in the runtime.

Answer (score 0):

So I didn't really solve this, but I think it has something to do with the module being set up as a library one. Once I added another one (Android in that case, although I doubt that matters) as an application and referenced to the first one from it, everything worked correctly. /shrug