# Gradle Error: Google Services error while sync the app

Tags: android, gradle, google-api

I'm facing problem with the Google Services. I want to add in SIGN IN API into my app but I could not sync the app due to the error below:

```
    Error:Could not find com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0.
Searched in the following locations:
    file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/google/gms/google-services/3.0.0/google-services-3.0.0.pom
    file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/google/gms/google-services/3.0.0/google-services-3.0.0.jar
    https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/google/gms/google-services/3.0.0/google-services-3.0.0.pom
    https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/google/gms/google-services/3.0.0/google-services-3.0.0.jar
Required by:
    DelSnapUser-Dometics:app:unspecified
```

And here is my Gradle:

```
  buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'}
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.delsnap_user_domestic.delsnapuser_dometics"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.+'
}
```

Please help me to solve... Thanks and appreciate :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
  buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
```

to

```
  buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter() // <-- Added
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
```

Comment: I think you are asking this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13923766/gradle-buildscript-dependencies

Comment: In other words, I do not think you need `maven { url` in the second `repositories` block of your question