# Unable to add Admob into an old gradle 2.3.0 project

Tags: android, gradle

So this is a little new to me, I am using adblock project and showing my website from webviewer but i want to not show my website's ads into it, so i used adblock project for the same. But somehow i am getting this weird error of not founding

com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.0

```
    Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.0
    Install Repository and sync project
    Show in File
    Show in Project Structure dialog
```

After i clicked on Install Repository and sync project the SDK manager says

```
Could not find dependency "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.0"
```

Configs:
In build.gradle(project)

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven {
      url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
```

And in build.gradle(Module:libadblockerplus-android-webviewapp)

```
 dependencies {
        compile project(':libadblockplus-android-settings')
        compile project(':libadblockplus-android-webview')
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.0'
    }
```

Comment: That fixed the issue. Thanks @stkent

Comment: Excellent; upgrading to an answer for better future-reference :)

Answer (score 0):

adding

```
maven { 
url "https://maven.google.com" 
}
```

to the other repositories block in your build.gradle file. Fixed the issue. Thanks @stkent

Answer (score 0):

You should add

```
maven {
    url "https://maven.google.com"
}
```

to the other `repositories` block in your build.gradle file.

From your posted snippet, it appears you have already added it to the `buildscript` block's list of `repositories`. However, those repositories are only used to search for dependencies for the *building* of your application. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13923766/gradle-buildscript-dependencies) for more discussion on the difference between the `repositories` and `buildscript.repositories` blocks.