# Repeating repositories in build.gradle

Tags: android, gradle

I have `build.gradle` in my Android app that starts with the following:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.0'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1'
    }
}

repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}

// ...
```

Probably I created this `build.gradle` with QT Creator or copied from somewhere a long time ago and my app builds well enough, but at least it looks strange.

It is not clear for me why is there repeating `repositories`? Should I remove one of them?

What `repositories` does `ext.kotlin_version` relate to in the code above, first or second?

For example, removing the second one causes build errors.

Comment: This will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13923766/gradle-buildscript-dependencies